# how to explain the result of print propety using js for...in in firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

[the code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgdvq/)

in chrome `2--567--911--11111--
2--567--9111--11111--`, 
in firefox `2--567--911--11111--
9111--567--11111--2--`

chrome order the numberical key,but what is strategy of  the firerox?

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on `for..in`:

> A `for...in` loop iterates over the properties of an object in an
>   **arbitrary** order

But you could do this to get your keys sorted numerically:

```
var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort(function(a,b){ return +a > +b });
```

And then loop or print them out.

Comment: Well, "random" is one of the definitions of "arbitrary". It can also be defined as "determined by individual preference or convenience rather than by necessity". I understand that "arbitrary" in that context simply means "up to the browser vendor". It is a known fact that object keys are listed in no particular order.

Comment: ok,i want to find the strategy of the firefox, do i have to to search it in firefox source code?

Comment: Why complicate things? It is irrelevant how it is implemented... You can use this solution and abstract into your own iterator function, or just change your data structure into an array of objects since arrays are properly indexed.